# Related Products are not visible in Product view page

Tags: magento-1.7, product, related-products

I am facing an issue that related products are not visible in product view page. I have called related products in view page like below,

In `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`,

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>`

In `catalog.xml`,

`<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>`

Still why related products are not shown in my product details page ?

Comment: did you do reindex, cache flush and so on ?

Comment: Yes I did , but still no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You name `name="catalog.product.related"` in your xml and call : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>`

It should be : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related') ?>` if your xml is formed correctly. You can also give an alias in your xml like : `as="related_products"`

In any case, it needs to be a child of the parent node in the xml.

Comment: `as="related_products"` fixed the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly. Sorry for the mistake.